# render_to_string doesn't find my erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render

I am trying to use `render_to_string` like this:

```
html_result = render_to_string(:template => 'template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout')
```

And I keep getting the following error:

> Missing template /template_160x600

However, if I render normally, I don't have any problem:

```
render 'template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout'
```

What am I missing here?

EDITED:

I have added the view directory like this:

```
render 'arts/template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout'
```

But now I just get:

```
Missing template arts/show, application/show with
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what is happening is that even though you are using `render_to_string`, Rails tries to do the default render for the show view afterwards.

So, if after render_to_string you don't want to render any view, just do this:

```
html_result = render_to_string(:template => 'art/template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout')
head :ok
```

or

```
html_result = render_to_string(:template => 'art/template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout')
render nothing: true
```

Answer (score 0):

When you render a template you must specify the path from the root of the template search paths (`app/views` for one), so if your template is in `app/views/art` you would use:

```
html_result = render_to_string(:template => 'art/template_160x600', layout: 'art_layout')
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you using `render` or `render_to_string`? Your examples and errors don't seem to match.  Can you post your controller code also?

Comment: Rails was automatically calling render after my render_to_string.